# How to override the cxf MessageSenderEndingInterceptor and take control over handleMessage method

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

i use jaxws:client tag and spring for consuming webservices.
In the above process, i want to use cxf interceptors before and after calling a webservice.

iam able to work with cxf interceptors with webservice returning proper soap fault and success response, but the inFaultInterceptor is not getting invoked in case of 
Http Status Code : 404
and also when the service is down...connect exception..

after analysing the error.. i found that exception is being thrown from the 
https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/MessageSenderInterceptor.MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.html

```
 /**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
  * regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
  * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  * with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  *
  * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  * KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
  * specific language governing permissions and limitations
  * under the License.
  */

 package org.apache.cxf.interceptor;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ResourceBundle;

 import org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.BundleUtils;
 import org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange;
 import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
 import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
 import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
 import org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit;

 /**
  * Takes the Conduit from the exchange and sends the message through it.
  */
  public class MessageSenderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
  private static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = BundleUtils.getBundle(MessageSenderInterceptor.class);
  private MessageSenderEndingInterceptor ending = new MessageSenderEndingInterceptor();


  public MessageSenderInterceptor() {
       super(Phase.PREPARE_SEND);
  }

  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      try {
           getConduit(message).prepare(message);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new Fault(new org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.Message("COULD_NOT_SEND", BUNDLE), ex);
         }    

          // Add a final interceptor to close the conduit
          message.getInterceptorChain().add(ending);
   }

      public class MessageSenderEndingInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
        public MessageSenderEndingInterceptor() {
              super(Phase.PREPARE_SEND_ENDING);
          }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
            try {
                getConduit(message).close(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Fault(new org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.Message("COULD_NOT_SEND", BUNDLE), e);
                }
        }
        }

    private Conduit getConduit(Message message) {
        Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();
        Conduit conduit = exchange.getConduit(message);
        if (conduit == null
            && (exchange.getOutMessage() != null
                || exchange.getOutFaultMessage() != null)) {
            conduit = OutgoingChainInterceptor.getBackChannelConduit(message);
        }
        return conduit;
    }

 }
```

My Question:  How to override this class in our project so that handleMessage of inner class can be customised ?
i have to get control in the fault interceptor before cxf fault with could not send message is thrown...

Comment: You can not use a fault Interceptor to capture the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your participation! I did use fault interceptor but the control does not come in to that in case of webservice down situation . Control comes in to handleMessage method only in case of soap fault response from webservice , but I want to get the control into fault interceptor in case of webservice down too. The exception is being thrown from above message sender implementation inbuilt cxf interceptor

Comment: You also want to stop the interceptor chain so method invocation do not raise an exception or just be aware in interceptor that has been a problem?

Comment: I want to write the payload into database with some customized framework so that the service call can be resumed from an esb ,and I don't  mind the running of interceptor chain, but I need a control in a custom interceptor in case of Java.xml.ws.webserviceexception

Comment: Ok, i think in this case you can use a FaultListener. Check details in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a FaultListener added to CXF Bus. The listener will capture also the http exceptions (404 by example) allowing you to execute your code before they are raised to invoking method.

For example

```
public class CxfFaultListenerImpl implements FaultListener{
    public boolean faultOccurred(final Exception exception,final String description,final Message message) {

        //return false to avoid standard CXF logging of exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Spring CXF configuration

```
<cxf:bus>
 <cxf:properties>
    <entry key="org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener">
        <bean id="cxfFaultListener" class="CxfFaultListenerImpl" />
    </entry>
 </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked , have one more question why the control is not coming in to this fault listener in case of service call returning proper soap fault? Also can I pass back some object back to the webservice calling class from this fault listener ?

Comment: Reading javadoc https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/logging/FaultListener.html seems that FaultListener only listen for application exceptions. I guess SOAP fault  are considered part of the normal flow of webservice. In `FaultListener` you have access to exchanged `Message`. You can add there some data. For example `message.setContent(Exception.class, new Exception("custom error"));`

Comment: Thank you , but Iam unable to get the object in the class-- PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().getContent(Some.class); this is getting returned as null

Comment: I have tested it creating a custom exception in FaultListener and catching it at method invocation (try-catch). The exception received is the custom one. Also the interceptor chain are stopped are interceptor.handleMessage methods are not called

Comment: Yes you are correct , Iam getting the object in case of throwing custom exception from fault listener , but what Iam looking for is , can we get the object from interceptor or listener without throwing exception using exchange object or message.setcontent?? Can you post the sample? Thanks

Comment: With 404 or connection errors you have no payload. I tried to get the message response code at Listener or Interceptor with `message.get(Message.RESPONSE_CODE)` but seem it is not available. I can not found a method to get the get the real error code using the Message